# Can't see options menu bar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

        val menuInflater = menuInflater

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.food_add , menu)

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        if(item.itemId == R.id.food_add_item){
            val action = ListFragmentDirections.actionListFragmentToRecipesFragment()
            Navigation.findNavController(this , R.id.fragmentContainerView).navigate(action)
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

I have 2 fragment which are connected to MainActivity with NavHostFragment. I'm trying to make a menu when you open it from right top corner to bring second fragment on the screen but I can't see the bar on the right corner top of the app(also I can't see the top bar at all I couldn't understand?). And since I can't see it, I can't test the menu part at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item  android:id="@+id/food_add_item" android:title="Add food"></item>

</menu>
```

[I need to see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRZla.png)

[Instead I see this when I run the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LDOF.png)

I want to see and control the menu bar and the menu.

Comment: It looks like the theme of your app is a `NoActionBar` theme (which removes the default action bar) and you aren't calling `setSupportActionBar` on a `Toolbar` in your `R.layout.activity_main` to add your own action bar. Did you intentionally use a `NoActionBar` theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the themes folder. For both day and night xml files. In the theme style, if parent contains something like "NoActionBar" u should change it. Like this code below:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.App" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

To something like:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.App" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```